ASP.NET Core MVC Scaffolding in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor projects
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 9 MVC project. I managed to put views and controllers in "razor ui" libraries (ie, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor projects), so I have a main web app, and modules with area/controllers/views aside. Everything is working and I can load and run controllers and views from my libraries.
However, at design time I miss the ASP.NET Core MVC contextual scaffolding options in the libraries (works at main web app), like create controller or view with the assistants.
I know I can do it from command line, but I am trying to make it work from visual studio, to select a model and write options in the UI. I need help to make it work.
If I edit the project library and manually change project type from Razor to Web:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

to:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

I got the menus (have to close/reopen the project), but the project is now a "web app". I have to keep them as razor libraries.
Here is my project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
<!--<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
      
      <EnableDefaultCompileItems>true</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
      <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
      
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\diccionarioparametros\Controllers\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\diccionarioparametros\Views\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\Pages\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared" Version="9.0.0" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="9.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="9.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="9.0.0" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="9.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Datos\Datos.csproj" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

